# Java get duplicated elements more than 2 list

Tags: java, list, duplicates

I have 9 list and I want to compare all of them and get duplicated elements.

I tried  `retainAll()` method but it deletes elements that is not duplicated.

For example when I only compare SUPPORT and PROJECT_AND_SUPPORT_NAMES I get duplicated value.

But when I compare like below it returns empty.

```
        MANAGEMENT_NAMES.retainAll(SUPPORT_NAMES);
        MANAGEMENT_NAMES.retainAll(PROJECT_AND_SUPPORT_NAMES);
        MANAGEMENT_NAMES.retainAll(SALES_NAMES);
        MANAGEMENT_NAMES.retainAll(MARKETING_NAMES);
        MANAGEMENT_NAMES.retainAll(ACADEMY_NAMES);
        MANAGEMENT_NAMES.retainAll(DEVELOPMENT_NAMES);
        MANAGEMENT_NAMES.retainAll(HR_AND_ADMINISTRATION_NAMES);
        MANAGEMENT_NAMES.retainAll(WAREHOUSE_NAMES);

        SUPPORT_NAMES.retainAll(PROJECT_AND_SUPPORT_NAMES);
        SUPPORT_NAMES.retainAll(SALES_NAMES);
        SUPPORT_NAMES.retainAll(MARKETING_NAMES);
        SUPPORT_NAMES.retainAll(ACADEMY_NAMES);
        SUPPORT_NAMES.retainAll(DEVELOPMENT_NAMES);
        SUPPORT_NAMES.retainAll(HR_AND_ADMINISTRATION_NAMES);
        SUPPORT_NAMES.retainAll(WAREHOUSE_NAMES);

        PROJECT_AND_SUPPORT_NAMES.retainAll(SALES_NAMES);
        PROJECT_AND_SUPPORT_NAMES.retainAll(MARKETING_NAMES);
        PROJECT_AND_SUPPORT_NAMES.retainAll(ACADEMY_NAMES);
        PROJECT_AND_SUPPORT_NAMES.retainAll(DEVELOPMENT_NAMES);
        PROJECT_AND_SUPPORT_NAMES.retainAll(HR_AND_ADMINISTRATION_NAMES);
        PROJECT_AND_SUPPORT_NAMES.retainAll(WAREHOUSE_NAMES);
.
.
.

        HR_AND_ADMINISTRATION_NAMES.retainAll(WAREHOUSE_NAMES);
```

I want to get result like :

Department A - Jerry

Department B - Chris

Department C - Jerry

Department D - Chris

Department E - Chris

Department F - Jerry

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What **precisely** do you mean by "duplicated"?  Do you mean elements that appear more than once in any one of the lists?  Do you mean elements that appear in more than one list?  Do you mean elements that appear in all of the lists?  Or something else?

Comment: For example Department A - Jerry, Stephen, Daniel and Department B - Chris, Earl, Ryan and Department C - Jerry, Brown, Micheal. And I want to get all duplicated names.

Comment: No.  I didn't ask you to give an example.  I asked you to say precisely ... in English ... what you mean by "duplicated" in this problem.  Examples are ambiguous.  (Didn't your teachers teach you the difference between a specification and an example?)

Comment: I couldn't understand what you mean. I want to get duplicated names in 9 list. If there is any same name in any list it will print.

Comment: I don't understand what >you< mean by *"I want to get duplicated names in 9 list. If there is any same name in any list it will print."*.  This is a problem.  (I could guess.  But if I have to guess, I might guess wrong.)  But ... hey ... I gave you 3 possible alternative meanings in my 1st comment.   Why don't you READ them, and tell me which of the 3 is what you mean?

Comment: @StephenC Ohh I am so sorry. I got it now. I want to get first option.

Comment: @BatuhanBakar please tell precisely what the problem is next time, instead of making people guess it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly **duplicate** is a name that appears in all the departments more than once. And as a result, you want to have duplicated names for each department separately.

> I want to get result like :
>
> Department A - Jerry
> Department B - Chris

So my idea is first to create a `Set` of all duplicates in all the departments. And then create `lists` of duplicates for each department separately based on the `Set`.

This solution has linear time complexity.

Method `getDuplicatesForAllDepartments()` iterates over all the names in all departments and counts the number of occurrences of each name. It retains only names that appear more than once and saves them to a `Set`.

Method `getDuplicatesForOneDepartments()` determines which names in the given department are contained in the `Set` of duplicates.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<String>> departments = List.of(SUPPORT_NAMES, PROJECT_AND_SUPPORT_NAMES, SALES_NAMES, ... etc);
//         * List.of() - works with Java 9 onwards
//        For Java 8 you can add departments one by one using Collection.addAll()
//        List<List<String>> departments = new ArrayList<>();
//        Collections.addAll(departments, SUPPORT_NAMES, PROJECT_AND_SUPPORT_NAMES, SALES_NAMES, ... etc);

        Set<String> allDuplicates = getDuplicatesForAllDepartments(departments);
        List<String> duplicates1 = getDuplicatesForOneDepartment(SUPPORT_NAMES, allDuplicates);
        List<String> duplicatesProjectAndSupport = getDuplicatesForOneDepartment(PROJECT_AND_SUPPORT_NAMES, allDuplicates);
        // ... etc
    }

    public static Set<String> getDuplicatesForAllDepartments(List<List<String>> departments) {
        return departments.stream()
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(UnaryOperator.identity(), 
                                               Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() > 1)
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
    
    public static List<String> getDuplicatesForOneDepartment(List<String> department, Set<String> allDuplicates) {
        return department.stream()
                .filter(allDuplicates::contains)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

The imperative implementations of methods `getDuplicatesForAllDepartments()` and `getDuplicatesForOneDepartment()` will look like this:

```
    public static Set<String> getDuplicatesForAllDepartments(List<List<String>> departments) {
        Map<String, Integer> nameToCount = new HashMap<>();
        for (List<String> department: departments) {
            for (String name: department) {
                nameToCount.merge(name, 1, Integer::sum);
            }
        }

        Set<String> duplicates = new HashSet<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: nameToCount.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() > 1) {
                duplicates.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
        return duplicates;
    }

    public static List<String> getDuplicatesForOneDepartment(List<String> department, Set<String> allDuplicates) {
        List<String> duplicates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String name: department) {
            if (allDuplicates.contains((name))) {
                duplicates.add(name);
            }
        }
        return duplicates;
    }
```

I've used your example to prove that both implementations a working.

```
        List<String> departmentA = List.of("Jerry", "Stephen", "Daniel");
        // for Java 8 Arrays.asList("Jerry", "Stephen", "Daniel");
        List<String> departmentB = List.of("Chris", "Earl", "Ryan");
        List<String> departmentC = List.of("Jerry", "Brown", "Micheal");

        List<List<String>> departments = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.addAll(departments, departmentA, departmentB, departmentC);
        System.out.println(getDuplicatesForAllDepartments(departments));
```

**output**

```
[Jerry]
```

Comment: I will try now.

Comment: When I try to getDuplicatesForAllDepartments method I get "Cannot resolve method 'of' in 'List' " error.

Comment: @BatuhanBakar you are using Java8? OK, I'll change the code

Comment: @BatuhanBakar If you don't feel very comfortable with streams I can reimplement these methods using plain for-loops.

Comment: I get this error : 'getDuplicatesForAllDepartments(java.util.List<java.util.List<java.lang.String>>)' in 'codeshake.base.BasePage' cannot be applied to '(java.util.List<java.lang.String>, java.util.List<java.lang.String>, java.util.List<java.lang.String>)'

Comment: It can be better with loops I think. This is my interview question. There was 11 question. I finished all of them except this. If there was a method like retainAll() but don't delete elements. It could be great

Comment: I still get the same error cannot be applied error. I use  ```  public static  List<String> SUPPORT_NAMES = new  ArrayList<>(); ``` for my lists. Is it wrong for your method ?

Comment: @BatuhanBakar copy the whole text of error, please

Comment: I coppied and write before 2 comment.

Comment: codeShakePage.getDuplicatesForAllDepartments(SUPPORT_NAMES,PROJECT_AND_SUPPORT_NAMES);  REDLINES AT SUPPORT_NAMES,PROJECT_AND_SUPPORT_NAMES and gives 'getDuplicatesForAllDepartments(java.util.List<java.util.List<java.lang.String>>)' in 'codeshake.base.BasePage' cannot be applied to '(java.util.List<java.lang.String>, java.util.List<java.lang.String>)' error

Comment: @BatuhanBakar That means you are parsing wrong arguments: the method expects a list of lists ( List<List<String>> ), but you've provided two lists instead

Comment: @BatuhanBakar you have to combine all the lists of names into one (`departments` list) and provide this list as an argument to `getDuplicatesForAllDepartments(departments)`

Comment: @BatuhanBakar the example of usage of `Collections.addAll()` is at the very bottom of the answer

Answer (score 1):

You said that this was the meaning of *duplicate* that you wanted:

> *"elements that appear more than once in any one of the lists"*

Here is a simple solution.

```
Set<String> duplicates = new HashSet<>();

for (List<String> list: lists) {
    Set<String> all = new HashSet<>();
    for (String s: list) {
        if (!all.add(s)) {
            duplicates.add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

The logic is that a string will only be added to `duplicates` if it was already in `all`.  (The `add` method will return `true` if the element *wasn't* in the set already.  Check the javadocs.)

Since you want elements that are duplicate within a given list, we need to reset `all` for each list.

This could be coded in other ways (e.g. using Java 8+ streams), but in a situation like this, the most important thing is that you can understand the code.

Comment: Where will I add 9 lists in this loop ?

Comment: For this example given by the PO in a comment, your code will produce no results, meanwhile name "Jerry" appears more the once (one time per department) `Department A - Jerry, Stephen, Daniel and Department B - Chris, Earl, Ryan and Department C - Jerry, Brown, Micheal. And I want to get all duplicated names. – Batuhan Bakar`

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko - I have implemented the interpretation that the OP explicitly stated is the correct one.  If he has contradicted himself in the example ... well that's not really my problem.  (I am frankly fed up with trying to work out what he actually means.  And I suspect that he may not know himself.)

Comment: @BatuhanBakar - That is what `lists` is supposed to signify: one or more lists that you are processing.